# logging in sql vs files vs aws which is faster in c# Applications

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, logging, log4net

Please help me to understand which one is better for logging performancewise.
logging in sql vs files vs aws which is faster in c# Applications

Comment: Guess what! In the end, SQL and AWS store data in files

Comment: Write a small minimal test app for each and profile...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you want to log useful information from your application (C#) somewhere to be able to refer to it (presumably when something goes wrong or to extract information for analytics).

Rule of thumb, in interprocess communications, maximum time is spent on sending data over network. If you apply this knowledge, you will be able to order your choices (and other options) from performance point of view.

As an indication order in terms of performance for few cases will be

1. Log file on the same drive as your program and being written from within the same process
2. Log file on a mounted drive on the same machine that runs your program and being written from within the same process
3. Log written in a database that resides on the same machine (localhost) as program
4. Log written in a database that resides on a different machine but in a local network
5. Log written on AWS which obviously will not be within your local network.
6. ...

This said there are other considerations as well. For example a DB in local high bandwidth network on a powerful machine may write faster than a low configuration machine (e.g. ordinary laptop) having DB and program. Similarly, use of Direct Connect or fibre line between AWS and local network boosts the performance many many folds. 
Thus, the answer is not straight forward, lot many factors contribute to change the order. Safest bet is to use log files on the same machine. You can always run a separate process to read asynchronously from the file and write wherever you wish.

Comment: Don't forget the difference between solid state disks and hard disks